# Cancel service fabric actor activation on ActivateAsync?

Tags: azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-actor

Is it possible to cancel activation on ActivateAsync, based on initialization code and the ActorProxy.Create  to return null?
For example, a web service asks the state of a device actor. Device with this Id does not exist actually. Can I return null on the actor create?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, for two reasons.

1. The object returned from `ActorProxy.Create` is a [proxy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicefabric.actors.client.actorproxy) that can interact with a (remote) Actor, it is not the Actor itself.
2. An Actor is automatically created just in time, if it's not already there when interacting with it, so you don't need to worry about its [life cycle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-actors-lifecycle).

To find out which Actors exist, you can interact with the [ActorService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-actors-platform).
`PagedResult<ActorInformation> page = await actorServiceProxy.GetActorsAsync(continuationToken, cancellationToken);`

Comment: So, if there is not actual device to be represented by the Actor,  the client will find it, when it calls actor's methods  getting errors? At least,could  raise an error on ActivateAsync, during first method invocation, instead such error handling, in every method?

Comment: You could create an actor (or service) that maintains a list of known device ids, and check that before referencing the Device Actor. That would save you the overhead of creating a Device Actor you cannot use.